# Best way to write the characteristic polynomial

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, notation, intuition

In linear algebra I've seen that there are two major different ways
to *write* the characteristic polynomial of a mapping $f$: As
$$
p_{f}=\pm\left(T-\lambda_{1}\right)^{m_{1}}\cdot\ldots\cdot\left(T-\lambda_{k}\right)^{m_{k}}
$$
with distinct $\lambda_{i}$ or as 
$$
p_{f}=\pm\left(T-\lambda_{1}\right)\cdot\ldots\cdot\left(T-\lambda_{n}\right)
$$
where the $\lambda_{i}$ are not necessarily distinct.

The only advantage I can see the latter expression has over the former
is that the eigenvalues are already given in an order from $1$ to
$n$, so it's easier to user the latter expression when doing something
like induction over the eigenvalues.

But this argument is not very convincing to me...what kind of situations (theorems)
do you know, where it is *definitely* better to use one expression
over the other ? What are the disadvantages of each of the expressions
?

Comment: I usually prefer the first representation, because that way I can know exactly how many eigenvectors I have to find for every eigenvalue, in order for the map to be diagonalizable.

Comment: I agree with @NoySoffer. I also wouldn't use `\cdot\ldots\cdot`. Instead I'd use only `\cdots`.

Comment: The characteristic polynomial is usually taken to be monic, so there is no need to use $\pm$.

Comment: @lhf I've seen in different texts both version appear.

Answer (score 1):

In bringing the matrix to Jordan canonical form (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_canonical_form) it is crucial to have the multiplicities you denoted $m_i$ so as to describe the blocks into which the matrix decomposes (up to conjugation).

On the other hand, computationally speaking the coincidence of eigenvalues is not stable, and from this point of view the significance of the Jordan canonical form is purely theoretical.  From the viewpoint of applications the second form may be more relevant.

Comment: If the coincidence of eigenvalues is not stable, then I'd guess any method of _ordering_ the eigenvalues runs into the same problem (the ordering is not stable). So the second method has the same difficulty, since giving it explicitly requires ordering the eigenvalues.

Comment: In computational approaches they don't order the eigenvalues. The "standard form" they get is more complicated than Jordan canonical form in that it has nonzero entries in the line both below and above the main diagonal.

Comment: Could you be more specific concerning the viewpoint of application ? (For example, for the theorem that tells you that any matrix, whose characteristic polynomial splits, is triangularisable, it is better to use the second form I think...)